# Table in the centre of the page + Table caption in centre

Tags: tables, tabularx, center

I have produced the following table:

[image]

I want to make it perfect as it appears to me that the title/caption of the table is not exactly centered. Moreover, I'd like to have this table in the centre of the page.
Surprisingly, if I copy this table on page 6 I do get the table in centre but for the first page of the appendix it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix Figure}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\section{Additional Tables and Figures} \label{appendixA}


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{OCCUPATIONS AND RELATIVE TASK INTENSITY}
  \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}
\label{tableA1}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\toprule
Occupation &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Communication\\ intensity\\ index\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Manual\\ intensity\\ index\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C/M\\ percentile\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
Four occupations with highest C/M values &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\hspace{3mm}Financial managers                              & 0.830                & 0.210                & 0.999                \\
\hspace{3mm}Managers of properties and real estate          & 0.740                & 0.210                & 0.997                \\
\hspace{3mm}Editors and reporters                           & 0.870                & 0.200                & 0.997                \\
\hspace{3mm}Operations and systems researchers and analysts & 0.640                & 0.200                & 0.990                \\
                                                &                      &                      &                      \\
Five occupations with average C/M values        &                      &                      &                      \\
\hspace{3mm}Cashiers                                        & 0.380                & 0.730                & 0.562                \\
\hspace{3mm}Cooks, variously defined                        & 0.320                & 0.670                & 0.530                \\
\hspace{3mm}Hairdressers and cosmetologists                 & 0.300                & 0.620                & 0.498                \\
\hspace{3mm}Repairers of industrial electrical equipment    & 0.360                & 0.770                & 0.490                \\
\hspace{3mm}Kitchen workers                                 & 0.280                & 0.620                & 0.489                \\
                                                &                      &                      &                      \\
Four occupations with lowest C/M values         &                      &                      &                      \\
\hspace{3mm}Vehicle washers and equipment cleaners          & 0.040                & 0.720                & 0.021                \\
\hspace{3mm}Furniture and wood finishers                    & 0.010                & 0.720                & 0.021                \\
\hspace{3mm}Roofers and slaters                             & 0.010                & 0.640                & 0.020                \\
\hspace{3mm}Drywall installers                              & 0.000                & 0.720                & 0.006                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table, which reproduce your problem. Is a page contain only your table? Itmay be use of `p` positioning option a solution to your problem (if I correctly understand what you after,

Comment: I believe you meant to add begin and end document code.  I have edited it.

Comment: Your table is to wide that it can be fir in text area, consequently it spill out right text border. Is make text in the first column in twi lines if needed an option?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only a few sub-headers, I think the easiest approach to minimise repetitions is to insert one extra column, set its fixed width to a size of the indentation, e.g. `3mm`, and use `\multicolumn` to merge cells which are not supposed to get indented.

A few points.
I changed the environment to `tabularx` with the `X` column-type; it adapts its column width so the column fills the remaining space in a table.
`\addlinespace[<optional v-sep>]` is a better way to add extra space since you use `booktabs`. Currently, in this line

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\hangindent=2em}m{#1}}
```

`X` is redefined to have middle vertical alignment with the numbers. This can be changed to`p{#1}` (top alignment) or `b{#1}` (bottom alignment). Because of the indentation, I also added `\hangiafter` to distinguish between the first and any subsequent line if the cell is too narrow to fit its content.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}   % Added for the X column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % Added for \Centering
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=3pt}


\begin{document}
\newpage
\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix Figure}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\section{Additional Tables and Figures}\label{appendixA}

%%% Added
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{3} m}{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}l@{}}{#2}}      % For unindented columns
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\hangindent=2em}m{#1}}                   % Redefines X
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[h]
  % \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \caption{OCCUPATIONS AND RELATIVE TASK INTENSITY}
  \label{tab:tableA1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{3mm} @{} X C{2.5cm}C{1.5cm}C{1.5cm} @{}}
    \toprule
    \toprule
    \mc[2]{Occupation}
      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Communication\\ intensity\\ index\end{tabular}
      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Manual\\ intensity\\ index\end{tabular}
      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C/M\\ percentile\end{tabular} \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[\normalbaselineskip]
    \mc{Four occupations with highest C/M values} && \\
    & Financial managers                              & 0.830 & 0.210 & 0.999 \\
    & Managers of properties and real estate          & 0.740 & 0.210 & 0.997 \\
    & Editors and reporters                           & 0.870 & 0.200 & 0.997 \\
    & Operations and systems researchers and analysts & 0.640 & 0.200 & 0.990 \\
    \addlinespace[\normalbaselineskip]
    \mc{Five occupations with average C/M values} && \\
    & Cashiers                                        & 0.380 & 0.730 & 0.562 \\
    & Cooks, variously defined                        & 0.320 & 0.670 & 0.530 \\
    & Hairdressers and cosmetologists                 & 0.300 & 0.620 & 0.498 \\
    & Repairers of industrial electrical equipment    & 0.360 & 0.770 & 0.490 \\
    & Kitchen workers                                 & 0.280 & 0.620 & 0.489 \\
    \addlinespace[\normalbaselineskip]
    \mc{Four occupations with lowest C/M values}  && \\
    & Vehicle washers and equipment cleaners          & 0.040 & 0.720 & 0.021 \\
    & Furniture and wood finishers                    & 0.010 & 0.720 & 0.021 \\
    & Roofers and slaters                             & 0.010 & 0.640 & 0.020 \\
    & Drywall installers                              & 0.000 & 0.720 & 0.006 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sorry, it is still unclear (to me), what you after.
- So, this answer is based on guessing
- See, if the following suggestion gives desired result

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\appendix
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix Figure}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\section{Additional Tables and Figures} 
\label{appendixA}
\vfil
    \begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{OCCUPATIONS AND RELATIVE TASK INTENSITY} 
\label{tableA1} 
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xccc @{}} 
    \toprule
Occupation 
    & \makecell{Communication\\ intensity index} 
        & \makecell{Manual\\ intensity index} 
            & \makecell{C/M\\ percentile}                       \\ 
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}>{\bfseries}l}{Four occupations with highest C/M values}    \\ 
Financial managers  
    & 0.830 & 0.210 & 0.999                                     \\ 
Managers of properties and real estate          
    & 0.740 & 0.210 & 0.997                                     \\ 
Editors and reporters                           
    & 0.870 & 0.200 & 0.997                                     \\ 
Operations and systems researchers and analysts 
    & 0.640 & 0.200 & 0.990                                     \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{@{}>{\bfseries}l}{Five occupations with average C/M values}                                           \\
    \addlinespace
Cashiers                                        
    & 0.380 & 0.730 & 0.562                                     \\
Cooks, variously defined                        
    & 0.320 & 0.670 & 0.530                                     \\ 
Hairdressers and cosmetologists                 
    & 0.300 & 0.620 & 0.498                                     \\ 
Repairers of industrial electrical equipment    
    & 0.360 & 0.770 & 0.490                                     \\ 
Kitchen workers                                 
    & 0.280 & 0.620 & 0.489                                     \\ 
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}>{\bfseries}l}{Four occupations with lowest C/M values}\\
Vehicle washers and equipment cleaners          
    & 0.040 & 0.720 & 0.021                                     \\
Furniture and wood finishers                    
    & 0.010 & 0.720 & 0.021                                     \\
Roofers and slaters                             
    & 0.010 & 0.640 & 0.020                                     \\
Drywall installers                              
    & 0.000 & 0.720 & 0.006                                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]